# Drawing arrows combined of 3 lines between flow chart elements

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I'm trying to draw an arrow connecting two elements like this:

[image]

Even when I use `-|` command.

```
\draw [arrow, very thick] (a1) -- (a2);
\draw [arrow] (a2) -- (a3);
\draw [arrow] (a3) -- (a4);
\draw [arrow] (a4) -- (a5);
\draw [arrow] (a5) -- (a6);
\draw [arrow] (a6) -| node[anchor=west]  {No} (a2);
\draw [arrow] (a6) -- node[anchor=west]  {Yes} (a7);
\draw [arrow] (a7) -- (a8);
```

When i compile this code
this is what i get an arrow that goes straight from 2nd decision to ACT2 :
[image]

Comment: Could [TikZ arrow positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56888/13304) help?

Comment: Please provide the full code you use to generate the image, not just a sniplet. Depending how `2nd` is made this is quite simple.

Comment: [Q102385](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102385) and all the linked ones.

Comment: Welcome. // However, it's no good idea to make us guessing what e.g. `arrow` or `(a2)` is going to be, or even replicate your code from guessing. As a test try compiling your snippet in a fresh file and provide the missing parts. Also you can easily shrink down your code to a few relevant elements, as not all ACTs are really needed ...

Comment: Your code fragment is not related to showed image ... please consider  @daleif comment!

Comment: Try `\draw[arrow] (a6) -- +(0.5,0) |- node[right] {No} (a2);` instead of `\draw[arrow] (a6) -| node[anchor=west] {No} (a2);`. (Or maybe use a smaller value than `0.5`.) For better help, you need to provide a full and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 0):

I used this method: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102390/308613
declaring a `line` style in `tikzset` like this:

```
line/.style={draw, -latex}
```

then creating a `\path` in `tikzpicture` body.

```
\node (s1) [process, yshift=-0.5cm] {ACT 1}; 
\node (s2) [process, below of=s1] {ACT 2};
\node (d1) [decision, below of=s2, yshift=-1.5cm] {DECISION 1}; 
\node (s3) [process, below of=d1,  yshift=-1.5cm] {ACT 3};

\path [line] (s1) -- (s2);
\path [line] (s2) -- (d1);
\path [line] (d1) -- (s3);

\path [line]  (d1.east) -- ([xshift=0.6cm]s2.east) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]s1.east) -- (s1.east);
```

The final result:

[image]

Comment: This answer is not very helpful Pleas add MWE (Minimal Working Example), which show how you solve your problem. You can also accept your answer ...

Comment: Please clarify your question via Edit. In this place questions are problems, whiel each answer is a solution. This is different to chatting forums. Stange as it feels in the beginning, it's very useful. // Please delete this "answer" (non-solution) after Editing. // We also liek your code and dislike following links ...

Comment: @MS-SPO It looks like an answer to me. Why don't you think this is a solution?

Comment: @cfr, it looks puzzling to me. Most important: probably nobody else can use the code posted, as many things are missing. So, if it's in doubt, whether it's an answer or an explanation of the initial question ... it's not good enough in my view. However, the OP is a beginner here, so there will be some hickups for now, which is ok.

Comment: @MS-SPO I agree it needs the code to be filled out, but it is clearly intended as an answer and not as clarification of the question. I honestly don't see how there can be any doubt about that. It demonstrates a technique which changes the route the arrow takes to avoid the problem in the question.

Comment: @cfr, ok, just to conclude, what would have helped me is a simple phrase like "My solution ...", "I found this approach ..." or similar.

Comment: Guys, what should I add to make my question and my answer valid?