# Arrow with three right angles (as to-path)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

Can anyone please help me how to draw the arrow in red?

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % do not print page number
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\pagecolor{white} 

\tikzset {
    startstop/.style={
        circle,
        rounded corners,
        minimum width=1cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered,
        draw=black!80,
        fill=white!100
    },
    interconnect/.style={
        circle,
        minimum width=0.25cm,
        minimum height=0.25cm,
        draw=black!80,
        fill=white!100
    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle,
        minimum width=3cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered,
        text width=3cm,
        draw=black!80,
        fill=white!100
    },
    decision/.style={
        diamond,
        minimum width=3cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered,
        draw=black!80,
        fill=white!100
    },
    % RECTANGULAR CONNECTOR ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/arrows-at-right-angles-on-a-tikzpicture-matrix
    descr/.style={
        fill=white,
        inner sep=2.5pt
    },
    connector/.style={
     -latex
    },
    rectangle connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
        pos=0.5
    },
    rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
    straight connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    },
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (START) [startstop] {Start};
\node (SETUP) [process, below of=START, yshift=0.0cm] {setup()};
\node (CON1) [interconnect, below of=SETUP, yshift=0.25cm] {};
\node (GEN-QUEST) [process, below of=CON1, align=center, yshift=0.25cm] {Generate\\new question};
\node (CON2) [interconnect, below of=GEN-QUEST, yshift=0.25cm] {};
\node (INPUT) [process, below of=CON2, align=center, yshift=0.25cm] {Get user\\input};
\node (LED) [process, below of=INPUT, align=center] {Turn LEDs on/off\\accordingly};
\node (CHECK-ANSWER) [decision, below of=LED, align=center, yshift=-0.75cm] {Correct\\answer?};

\draw [arrow] (START) -- (SETUP);
\draw [arrow] (SETUP) -- (CON1);
\draw [arrow] (CON1) -- (GEN-QUEST);
\draw [arrow] (GEN-QUEST) -- (CON2);
\draw [arrow] (CON2) -- (INPUT);
\draw [arrow] (INPUT) -- (LED);
\draw [arrow] (LED) -- (CHECK-ANSWER);
\draw [rectangle connector=3.5cm] (CHECK-ANSWER) to node[descr] {no} (CON2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // We had the same or very similar question here today: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702104/245790 ...

Comment: Er, I think that's three bends ...

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton, you're right, I edited the title.

Comment: You got two answers which both solve your problem. So, it is time to accept one of them which you the most liked (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer).)

Comment: Thank you Zarko. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more sophisticated code, which is based on the use of the Ti*k*Z libraries `chains`, `positioning` and `ext.paths.ortho`. Due to them the code is much shorter and concise:

- nodes are connected in vertical chain, where are by use of the macro `join` are connected by arrows
- for feedback are used `ext.paths.ortho` library (it is part of `tikz-ext` package)

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % defined in the tikz-ext package
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\tikzset {
     arr/.style = {-Stealth},
    base/.style = {draw=black!80, align=center},
   startstop/.style = {base, circle, minimum size=1cm},
interconnect/.style = {base, circle, minimum size=2.5mm, node contents = {}},
     process/.style = {base, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm},
    decision/.style = {base, diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm},
         lbl/.style = {fill=white, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, pos=#1}
        }

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going below
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]
\node (START) [startstop]   {Start};
\node (SETUP) [process]     {setup()};
\node (CON1)  [interconnect];
\node (GEN-QUEST) [process] {Generate\\new question};
\node (CON2)  [interconnect];
\node (LED)   [process]     {Turn LEDs on/off\\accordingly};
\node (CHECK-ANSWER) [decision] {Correct\\answer?};
    \end{scope}
% arrows not included in join macro
\draw[arr] (CHECK-ANSWER) r-rl[rl distance=12mm] (CON2) node[lbl=0.1] {No};
\draw[arr] (CHECK-ANSWER.south) -- ++ (0,-1) node[lbl=0.5] {Yes}
                          r-rl[rl distance=28mm] (CON1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As variation to the existing `rectangle connector`, you can define another style:

```
double rectangle connector/.style={
    connector,
    to path={(\tikztostart) |- ++(#1) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget)},
    pos=0.25
},
double rectangle connector/.default={2cm,-2cm},
```

And then add to your drawing:

```
\draw [double rectangle connector={5cm,-2cm}] (CHECK-ANSWER) to node[descr] {yes} (CON1);
```

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset {
    startstop/.style={
        circle,
        rounded corners,
        minimum width=1cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered,
        draw=black!80,
        fill=white!100
    },
    interconnect/.style={
        circle,
        minimum width=0.25cm,
        minimum height=0.25cm,
        draw=black!80,
        fill=white!100
    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle,
        minimum width=3cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered,
        text width=3cm,
        draw=black!80,
        fill=white!100
    },
    decision/.style={
        diamond,
        minimum width=3cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered,
        draw=black!80,
        fill=white!100
    },
    % RECTANGULAR CONNECTOR ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/arrows-at-right-angles-on-a-tikzpicture-matrix
    descr/.style={
        fill=white,
        inner sep=2.5pt
    },
    connector/.style={
        -latex
    },
    rectangle connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget)},
        pos=0.5
    },
    rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
    double rectangle connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path={(\tikztostart) |- ++(#1) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
        pos=0.25
    },
    double rectangle connector/.default={2cm,-2cm},
    straight connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    },
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    arrow/.style={thick, ->, >=stealth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (START) [startstop] {Start};
\node (SETUP) [process, below of=START, yshift=0.0cm] {setup()};
\node (CON1) [interconnect, below of=SETUP, yshift=0.25cm] {};
\node (GEN-QUEST) [process, below of=CON1, align=center, yshift=0.25cm] {Generate\\new question};
\node (CON2) [interconnect, below of=GEN-QUEST, yshift=0.25cm] {};
\node (INPUT) [process, below of=CON2, align=center, yshift=0.25cm] {Get user\\input};
\node (LED) [process, below of=INPUT, align=center] {Turn LEDs on/off\\accordingly};
\node (CHECK-ANSWER) [decision, below of=LED, align=center, yshift=-0.75cm] {Correct\\answer?};

\draw [arrow] (START) -- (SETUP);
\draw [arrow] (SETUP) -- (CON1);
\draw [arrow] (CON1) -- (GEN-QUEST);
\draw [arrow] (GEN-QUEST) -- (CON2);
\draw [arrow] (CON2) -- (INPUT);
\draw [arrow] (INPUT) -- (LED);
\draw [arrow] (LED) -- (CHECK-ANSWER);
\draw [rectangle connector=3.5cm] (CHECK-ANSWER) to node[descr] {no} (CON2);
\draw [double rectangle connector={5cm,-2cm}] (CHECK-ANSWER) to node[descr] {yes} (CON1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Jasper!